# Is there a way to query mysql to find arabic text in a field?

Tags: mysql, regex

I am trying something like this but I am not sure if I have the regex right

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = HEX(source_text) REGEXP '^(\u0621-\u064A\u0660-\u0669 )'
```

Comment: You can search trough strings. So i think that this should also be possible since MySQL is also used by Arabs

Answer (score 0):

This works. Arabic is part of Unicode. Thanks to [Frank da Cruz's linguistic samples.](http://www.columbia.edu/~fdc/utf8/index.html)

```
 SELECT ' أنا قادر على أكل الزجاج و هذامن' RLIKE CONCAT('^.*', 'على', '.*$')
```

I suspect your use of `HEX(source_text)` is incorrect here.

Comment: `RLIKE` only works with bytes.  Hopefully Arabic has no capitalization, or alternate encodings (such as optional vowel accents)?